# Exposing Collection or Set for public API

Tags: java, collections, set, public

It is said that coding against the interface rather than a specific type is a good practice . In other words we expose generic interfaces instead of specific implementation while creating an API.

For example:

```
public Collection<Model> getUniqueModels();
public void setUniqueModels(Collection<Model> modelCollection);
```

But my question is what if I want the consumer to know that I will only return a unique set of models i.e all models would be different.

```
public Set<Model> getUniqueModels();
public void setUniqueModels(Set<Models> modelSet);
```

Is this a bad way to create a publc API? What if I use the collection one and the cosumers sends a list of duplicate models which won't work?

Comment: `coding against the interface rather than a specific type`: `Set` is also an interface. If you expect a `Set`, there's no point in saying `Collection` in the signature, is there?

Comment: I agree but please see the answer below. That is what my doubt was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good approach to designing "lenient" public APIs is for the types to be as specific as you can on things that you return, and as forgiving as you can on the things that you accept.

In this particular situation, you should return a `Set<Model>` and accept `Collection<Model>`, with the understanding that any duplicates would be ignored:

```
public Set<Model> getUniqueModels();
public void setUniqueModels(Collection<Model> modelSet);
```

or even

```
public void setUniqueModels(Collection<? extends Model> modelSet);
```

An API like that would tell users that they would not get any duplicates among the models from the getter, but it would accept collections of other types in the setter, in case that users of your API prefer to validate uniqueness in some other way (e.g. by pulling a `List<Model>` from a database with a query that ensures uniqueness).

> what if the consumer sends a list of duplicates unknowingly?

There are two approaches to this: you could silently ignore this, or you could validate and raise an exception.

The first approach (i.e. ignore the duplicates) is usually good enough: that is how Java APIs do it, for example, when constructing a `HashSet<T>` from a collection. Rather than users making unique sets all over the place, you could make a unique set once, and let them pass duplicates to you.

However, even the second approach gives users more flexibility than accepting a `Set<Model>`, because it leaves the decision on making the collection unique up to them.

Comment: Did you mean return a Collection<Model> and accept Set<Model>?

Comment: I see your point but my only concern is what if the consumer sends a list of  duplicates unknowingly?

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. If I go with the first approach won't that be losing data without the consumer knowing?? I love the second approach because that give the api to tell the consumer that an exception will be thrown if there are duplicates but still is flexible to accept a collection.

Comment: Hmm did not notice that. Thanks a lot. Do you mind adding your second to last comment in the answer. That will be a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Set` interface still conforms to the principle of programming to the interface. There's nothing wrong with it as long as it defines the semantics of the collection you intend to use, in this case having all elements unique within the collection. Both `Collection` and `Set` are interfaces, but the latter makes the consumer understand that there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable to expose the `Set` interface - this is after all still an interface and not a concrete class. It *would* be bad practice to expose a specific concrete class such as `HashSet` , but you're fine exposing *and* consuming a `Set`. I don't think there is any need to expose only the highest level interface.